# "There is a problem parsing the package" in samsung galaxy Note5

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am building an application which is running perfectly in samsung galaxy s4 , Motorola g3 , and Micromax Canvas HD. 
When I am trying to install it on my samsung galaxy NOTE5. it is giving parsing error. 
I can not figure out what to do in this case.

I already turned on `Unknown Source` from device administration.

My manifest.xml file is as under:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

I am attaching screen shot of the error also.
[image]